# Visual Studio Extension, dll deployment and locking [C#, VSIX]

Tags: c#, vsix

I need some help using `CodeAnalysisCSharp` in my VSIX project.

The issue I'm currently having is that the necessary dlls are not "deployed" when installing the extension. I've had to manually copy/paste these files to the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE` folder, for it to "work".

```
System.Numerics.Vectors.dll
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
System.Memory.dll
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll
```

I have created an extension project and added a custom command. This command should be able to use the `CodeAnalysisCSharp` to navigate the syntax tree of a C# file.

I'd very much like for the installer file (.vsix) to be able to deploy the dll dependencies, just like you'd expect it to, I just don't know how or where to look to make this happen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that if you use the vsixmanifest file to add assets, and give it a sub folder, it doesn't get packaged correctlty. The files will be copied correctly, but the reference to the dlls are not correct, so you get a "dll not found" exception.
In general the vsixmanifest designer, seems to be riddled with quirks where you need to edit the xml code to be sure that the values are set correctly.